# "When" + future perfect usage

Tags: tenses, adverbs, future, perfect-aspect, when

A Scots friend of mine corrected my usage of future perfect in this construction:

> Right, see you in five years when your mother tongue will have taken another ten steps back.

Maybe the construction merits a comma between *years* and *when*, but in my mind (and Chat-GPT4's mind) there isn’t any problem.

He’s adamant that it should be phrased as:

> Right, see you in five years when your mother tongue has taken another ten steps back.

Who’s right?

Comment: English tends to simplify 'tense structures' (temporal constructions_ where ambiguity doesn't arise, so the second variant (I'd prefer the comma added) is idiomatic. But (again I'd add the comma) the first variant is also acceptable, and the necessary version if 'by' is added before 'when / which time'.

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. In my experience native *German* speakers are more likely to use the explicitly future verb form in the cited context - which isn't *wrong*, but most native Anglophones just stick with "Present Perfect in the Future". Simplest is usually best!

Comment: @TinfoilHat indeed, it was in chat, and I had left the "I'll" out.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You prefer a comma in the second, not the first?

Comment: @Araucaria That's not what I said.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I’ve had a more careful read …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They’re both correct, if we're prepared to play loose with the punctuation. But although they look suspiciously similar they’re actually structured quite differently.

Consider the following

1. *I’ll see you when the sun will come up. (ungrammatical)
2. I’ll see you when the sun comes up.

In the sentences above the string *when the sun (will) come up* is an adjunct, which is to say it is a modifier of the preceding verb phrase. And just as with other temporal adjuncts beginning with words like *after, before, until* and so forth, the use of *will* is restricted. It can only be used to indicate willingness, not general epistemic predictions:

3. *I'll stay with you after/ before/ until the concert will start. (ungrammatical)
4. I'll stay with you after/ before/ until the concert starts.

However, look at what happens if we do this:

5. I'll see you at 6am, when the sun will come up.
6. I'll see you at 6am when the sun comes up.

In (5) above we see that *will* is perfectly grammatical. And in (6) is's perfectly possible to use the simple present without any *will*. However, the comma that I've chosen to include in (5) is a clue as to why this is so. The string *when the sun will come up*  is a supplementary (or non-defining, if you prefer) relative clause. The relative word *when*, here, has the phrase *6am* as it's antecedent. As it is not a temporal adjunct of the preceding clause, it is not subject to the same restrictions regarding the use of *will*

**The Original Poster's question**

Consider the following example:

> 7. *See you when your mother tongue will have taken 10 steps back. (Ungrammatical)

The sentence above is ungrammatical. It flaunts the constraint about using epistemic *will* in regular temporal adjuncts. However, if we do stick a suitable temporal adjunct in, we can use the  adjunct as an antecedent for a following relative clause:

> 8. Right, see you in **5 years**, **when** your mother tongue will have taken another 10 steps back.

This looks very similar to the following:

> 9. Right, see you in 5 years when your mother tongue has taken another 10 steps back.

However, in (9) above, the word *when* is not a relative word but a normal preposition/subordinating conjunction just like *after* or *before. [And for grammar buffs, whereas the relative clause in (8) has a gap in it corresponding to the word *when*, the clause after *when* in (9) is just a regular finite content clause].

Technically speaking, some people who think that punctuation is very important might complain that the Original Poster's own example would be better with a comma before the *when*. However, something about the length of the *when*-phrase seems to make it more acceptable without here. OP's friend, then, might have a punctuation niggle, but there's no grammar objection to be had.

Comment: Indeed. This reading becomes more obvious if you replace the "when" with "by which time."

Comment: @alphabet Yes, that's a great way of illustrating it. Do you mind if I integrate that into the post (not tonight, though!)?

Comment: I do not mind; feel free to do so!

Comment: @alphabet Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that *I will see you before the sun will have come up* is ungrammatical?

Answer (score 2):

Your use the future perfect is actually quite standard:

> We use the future perfect simple (will/won't have + past participle) to talk about something that will be completed before a specific time in the future. ("[Future continuous and future perfect](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/future-continuous-future-perfect)," British Council)

You haven't explained why your friend insisted that it was wrong, and offhand I can't think of what the reason might be. (Perhaps there's a feature of Scots that I'm unfamiliar with.)

Keep in mind that the first clause seems to have dropped its subject and part of its verb phrase. If we restored them, then the future tense would be natural:

> Right, [[I'll]] see you in 5 years when your mother tongue will have taken another 10 steps back.

I think that it's now more obvious that the future perfect is acceptable for the second clause.

Note that use of the present perfect for the second clause, as your friend suggested, is also acceptable. (You can search the same British Council website for a discussion of the use of the present tense for future action.)

Comment: Thank you. He mentioned something in the same vein as some of the other contributors here, that 'when' does not go well together with the future construct (even though it's future perfect).


I'd like to mark this as the answer, but I'd like to wait a little bit more until Fev comes back, he hasn't made any comment after his initial answer below.

Comment: From the article, `In five years' time, I'll have finished studying medicine.` I don't think this addresses my friend's raised issue. The insertion of `when` (when I'll have finished) here would render the sentence invalid according to Cambridge and Jakub Marian below.

Comment: If your friend is making that claim, then the burden of proof is really on him to back it up. However, there's no shortage of counterexamples that I think are self-evident: "I know when the sun will set," etc.

Comment: @Titus Toia Using 'by when' or 'by which time' instead of 'when' certainly gives a grammatical result in 'Right, see you in five years when your mother tongue will have taken another ten steps back.' Arguably, the hedged version ('should' in place of 'will') is more felicitous to how events actually tend to pan out.

Answer (score -1):

Your friend is right.

And so is [jakubmarian.com](https://jakubmarian.com/will-after-when-in-english/) when explaining that:

> ***We never use the future tense in time clauses*** (introduced by phrases like “after”, “as soon as”, “before”, etc.) in English. Should we need to express the idea of something happening, say, after something else in the future, we use the present tense in the time clause and the future tense or a command in the main clause.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/when) confirms that:

> **In references to the future** with ***when***, *we use the present simple or the present perfect in the when-clause*, ***not the future with shall and will***:
>
> - When the new park ***opens***, I’***ll go*** there every day.
> - Not: <del>When the new park will open, I’ll go there every day.</del>

You may be confused by the fact that you are using future perfect, not future simple. But the rule still stands. *No **will** after **when*** in temporal clauses.

Comment: 'When X will have happened' is not the same as 'when X will happen'. 'I'll come next month, when the new park will be open / have opened.' In fact, in parentheticals, even say  'I'll come next month, when the new park will open.' is fine.

Comment: "Will have PP" is a statement of probability/surety, just as it is in "Yesterday he will have left work before 5."